# Macro for renaming of threading code is not working

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to make a macro that allows me call threading macro with 'thr' name rather than '~>' code. I tried:

```
(require threading)
(define-syntax-rule (thr body ...)
  (require threading)
  (~> body ... ) )

(thr " checking " string-trim println)
```

But it does not work. The error is:

```
 define-syntax-rule: too many forms in: (~> body)
```

I also tried with only one body statment but still it does not work:

```
(define-syntax-rule (thr2 body )
  (require threading)
  (~> body ) )
```

Comment: The error is still the same. If I remove (require threading) from macro, it runs but gives output: #<procedure:string-trim>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest way to do this in Racket is:

```
(define-syntax thr (make-rename-transformer #'~>))
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But I still need to add (require threading) before this. Is there any way I can include this also in the macro?

Comment: It is included so to speak. If you provide `thr` and use it in another file, you don't have to require threading.

Comment: You can also just do `(require (rename-in threading [~> thr]))`, which effectively does the same exact thing, or even `(provide (rename-out [~> thr]))`, then import the providing module.